# Error al configurar base de datos remota para laravel

Tags: laravel

Actualmente tengo un proyecto local conectado a mi base de datos local, pero quiero conectar ese proyecto local a mi base de datos en la nube, he realizado esto pero sin éxito:

```
.env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=ipdelservidorremoto
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=nombre
DB_USERNAME=usuario
DB_PASSWORD=clave

'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'ipdelservidorremoto'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'nombre'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'usuario'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'clave'),
```

Al tratar de entrar al sistema me dice:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Alguno me podría orientar para saber que me falta por hacer.

Comment: El problema parece venir de el servidor, ¿en que entorno se encuentra esta base de datos? ¿tienes instalado correctamente **MySQL** allí?

Comment: a la hora de crear el usuario le asignaste que la conexion puede venir desde una ip especifica o cualquiera?

Comment: el entorno es dev, tiene phpmyadmin instalado, y si esta configurado para que acepte conexiones any host

Comment: @darcas vale recuerda que en las configuraciones de **MySQL** tienes que establecer esta variable así `bind-address   = 0.0.0.0` para que pueda atender otras IP y por supuesto recuerda reiniciar el servicio de `mysql-server` una vez cambiada la configuración

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, me podrias indicar en donde realizo éste cambio?

Comment: Pues por supuesto esto depende se tu entorno en el servidor, si es un VPS en un sistema *Debian* o *Ubuntu* puede estar en esta ruta `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. Pero si es un Shared Hosting esto ya depende se tu proveedor o si usas **CPanel**, por ejemplo

Comment: Recuerda mencionarme con un **@** en los comentarios para que yo pueda recibir una notificación ;)

Comment: @Josbert gracias por la ayuda